# How to listen for a Webview loading a URL in linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I have a url page t.I want to load a url from localhost for linux client .How can load url programmatically on linux.Please anyone can help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: not clear what you want. can you elaborate it more?

Comment: @Jayesh i have a url suppose http://localhost:2721/indexlist.html .how can i load this url from a browser in linux?

Comment: First you wrote "_How can load url programmatically_", then you wrote "_how can i load this url from a browser_". Surely this isn't supposed to mean the same, is it?